# Rewrite URL on response, not on request

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, websphere, portal

I need to rewrite an URL in order to have a good-looking URL on an IBM WebSphere Portal website.
For now, the URL looks like this:
`http://www.mydomain.com/wps/portal/Internet/home/!ut/p/b1/jZDRCoIwFIafpRfYji5JLqULdZVDYWK7iSGHGLgpeRJ6-_QBJP-7D77v5ueGN9wEO7mXJdcH2y1sjk99r6S6phHEl0pALtICSn0TquzlaKwLsdhv68UZDnIRlMxOkEtQoq7qKI029rCyBP71khs7OuYC4TsgMeqH-QBmW_rYzhGODGcM6DHQyIus98gHr3XzTXY_xAz1IQ!!/dl4/d5/L2dJQSEvUUt3QS80SmtFL1o2X1VNkUpPS0cxMDhDUjMwSTNHTjBRVUwzOEww/`

I'd like to have this kind of URL returned to the visitors: 
`http://www.mydomain.com/wps/portal/Internet/home/`

**But** I need to keep the part after "!ut" in the request sent to the portal because we need those parameters.
So, my idea would be to rewrite the URL **after** the process done by the portal.

I think that Apache URL Rewriting works like this :

1. The user send the request : `www.mydomain.com/wps/portal/?vs=Internet&page=home`
2. Apache gets the request and rewrites it like this : `www.mydomain.com/wps/portal/Internet/home/`
3. The application (in my case a portal) gets the request `www.mydomain.com/wps/portal/Internet/home/` and processes it
4. The application sends back the response with the URL `www.mydomain.com/wps/portal/Internet/home/!ut/p/b1/jZDRCoIwF...Eww/`
5. The WebBrowser displays the new URL in its address bar

How can I make it work like this:

1. The user send the request : `www.mydomain.com/wps/portal/?vs=Internet&page=home`
2. Apache gets the request and pass it unchanged to the application
3. The application (in my case a portal) gets the request `www.mydomain.com/wps/portal/?vs=Internet&page=home` and processes it
4. The application sends back the response with the URL `www.mydomain.com/wps/portal/Internet/home/!ut/p/b1/jZDRCoIwF...Eww/`
5. Apache gets the response and rewrites it like this : `www.mydomain.com/wps/portal/Internet/home/`
6. The WebBrowser displays the new URL in its address bar

Do you know if this is possible?

You may know a solution without Apache URL rewriting: I'm interrested too.

Comment: As far as I know, Apache mod_rewrite works only on server side and has no client side effect - appache gets an url reques and transforms it to path - so user can load urls of files that does not exist.
But, you can use [R] mod rewrite parameter to redirect user to url after performing regular expression.